# Theme Translation?

Tags: themes, translation

I've download a theme called [Contango](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/contango) from Wordpress Themes Repository.
The theme have a folder called "languagues" and have a file called "contango.po".
I could open that file and do translation, but nothing changed.

- How could I translate this theme into my own language?

Thanks so much and apologize for my newbie question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translation files must be named {locale}.po (e.g. `en_US.po` in order to be recognized. Rename your language translation file accordingly.

See more in the Codex: [i18n for developers](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers).

Comment: Thank you! But, how could I translate this tag: "% Comments"

Comment: That's a separate question. You need to add a proper gettext wrapper and a textdomain. Refer to the Codex link in the answer, and check the site for related questions, as it's probably been covered here before.